# Vue.js event passing issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a global child component with a button click event for adding up two numbers a and b that bound with customized properties, and then show the result on the parent component by triggering the function showResult().

I use "this.$emit("pAdd",v)" to trigger a customized event pAdd and call function showResult() on parent component to change the result value and show by {{result}}.

However, it doesn't work.

Could someone kindly help me figuring up this issue?

```
        <h1>To Add</h1>
        <my-child :a="5" :b="33" v-on:pAdd="showResult"></my-child>
        <h3>\{\{result\}\}</h3>

  <script>

        Vue.component('my-child', {
            props:['a','b'],
            template: "<button @click='addme'>Add them</button>",
            methods:{
                addme:function(){
                    var v = this.a + this.b;
                    // it works here
                    console.log(this.a,'+',this.b,'=',v)
                    // trigger event on parent component
                    this.$emit("pAdd",v)
                }
            }
        })

    var app = new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data:{
            result: 0
        },
        methods:{
            showResult:function(cval){
                console.log('showResult: ',cval)
                this.result = cval;
            }
        }
    })

  </script>
```

Comment: This may be because of the camel case in the html attribute. Try `v-on:p-add=""`. (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case)

Answer (score 0):

Change `v-on:pAdd` to `v-on:p-add`